# Inputting a list of strings Python

Tags: python, string, similarity

I have modified a Python code to create a a simple string similarity.

However, I'm trying to do is a user input, where I want the second user input (words) to contain a list of words so that I can compare between words.

```
    '''
Input the English words in w1, and
the translated Malay words in the list
'''
w1 = raw_input("Enter the English word: ")
words = raw_input("Enter all the Malay words: ")
## The bits im not sure what to code
wordslist = list(words)

for w2 in wordslist:
    print(w1 + ' --- ' + w2)
    print(string_similarity(w1, w2))
    print
```

When I entered, it seems to make a string similarity with the whole 'w1' input, with all single characters in 'words' input. All I want is for example

w1 = United Kingdom
words = United Kingdom, United Kingdoms, United States, Kingdmo.

Then it does a measure where

```
United Kingdom --- United Kingdom
United Kingdom --- United Kingdoms
United Kingdom --- United Sates
United Kingdom --- Kingdmo
```

and so on.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.split` to get a list of words:

```
>>> strs = "United Kingdom, United Kingdoms, United States, Kingdmo"
>>> strs.split(",")
['United Kingdom', ' United Kingdoms', ' United States', ' Kingdmo']
```

**help** on `str.split`:

```
>>> str.split?
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
from the result.
```

Comment: Sorry for asking a silly question, but how do I attain this from a user input? I've tried using str.split(",") under my user input, it still process the strings individually (every character).
Thanks!

Comment: @user1433571 The words entered by user  must be separated by commas(similar to what you posted in question). and then use `words = words.split(",")`.